# Laravel join tables

Tags: php, laravel, join

I have 2 tables and I need to `join` those tables.
I need to `select`  `id` and `nam`e from `galleries`, where share `gal.id = galleries.id` and `user_id = auth::id()`.

**Tables:**

```
Galleries: id, name
Share: gal_id, user_id
```

Please show me example in laravel. And I need to display it.

Comment: Please post the sql for the table and the code that you are using to access it.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

To achieve this, you have Relationship in Eloquent ORM. The official website states :

> Of course, your database tables are probably related to one another. For example, a blog post may have many comments, or an order could be related to the user who placed it. Eloquent makes managing and working with these relationships easy. Laravel supports many types of relationships:

You can read all about eloquent relationship over [here](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#relationships)

If you do not want to use relationship, following is an example on how to join two tables :

```
   DB::table('users')
->select('users.id','users.name','profiles.photo')
->join('profiles','profiles.id','=','users.id')
->where(['something' => 'something', 'otherThing' => 'otherThing'])
->get();
```

The above query will join two tables namely `users` and `profiles` on the basis of `user.id = profile.id` with two different conditions, you may or may not use `where` clause, that totally depends on what you are trying to achieve.