# How to join two tables in Laravel eloquent

Tags: laravel, join

I am trying to join two table in laravel 5.2 but I am getting no result. My fillable model for one of model1 is:

```
protected $fillable = [
    'number',
    'message',
    'name',
    'time',
    'utc',
    'created_at',
    'updated_at'
];
```

And another model2 is:

```
protected $fillable =  [
  'id',
  'Number',
  'Full_Name',
  'Type',
  'Email',
  'created_at',
  'updated_at'
];
```

I am using this code to generate join table:

```
DB::table('model1')\
        ->select('model1.id','model2.Number')\
        ->join('model2','model1.number','=','model2.Number')\
        ->get();
```

I am using this answer [Join Answer for laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27459380/laravel-join-tables)

I am getting the result using this join method. How can I get all the values using laravel eloquent.

Comment: Could you possibly post some sample data?

Comment: In model1 number are like 123456 and in model2 Number is 123456 it is simple

Comment: Your join is correct. Without data, I am not sure how we can help.

Answer (score 0):

As i understand your question you can simply join these two table by using following code and get the data.
  `$datas = DB::table('model1')->join('model2', 'model1.id', '=', 'model2.Number')
    ->get();`