# Laravel Eloquent find rows with one common unknown field

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

I have one table

```
inbox

| inboxid   | user_id  |
| SDFHK2D   | 123      | 
| SDFHK2D   | 124      | 
| GGGFHK2   | 125      |
| GGGFHK2   | 126      |
```

What I want to fetch is:

Records which is common for both users from inbox table only. (AGAIN NO JOIN)
Something like this

```
Select * 
from inbox
where [ user_id = 123 , user_id = 124 ] 
AND inboxid is COMMON
```

So basically I want to fetch all inbox id's which are common between user 123 and user 124

How can I do it with Laravel Eloquent or by simple SQL query?

```
Result Required 

| inboxid   | p_user_id |  s_user_id  | 
| SDFHK2D   | 123       |  124        |
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel join tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27459380/laravel-join-tables)

Comment: No it doesn't because this question is not related to join. This is related to SQL to find record with common field value which is unknown

Comment: Why don't you want JOINS?

Comment: @steven7mwesigwa I just need to fetch records of inboxuid shared between two users

Answer (score 1):

Do a `GROUP BY`, use `HAVING` to make sure both 123 and 124 are there:

```
select inboxid, min(user_id) as p_user_id, max(user_id) as s_user_id  
from inbox
where user_id in (123, 124)
group by inboxid
having count(distinct user_id) > 1
```

If you also want other pairs than 123/124 having the same inboxid, simply skip the `WHERE` clause.